# contenteditable moves the cursor outside the block

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

if you place another html block with the contenteditable="false" attribute in the contenteditable block, then the cursor moves outside the block as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Try to start removing the word "remove" in the example. And the cursor will go beyond the block.
Is it possible to solve this problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/weckdjp4/

```css
.test-block {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 2px;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" contenteditable="true" id="test">hi <div class="test-block" contenteditable="false">test</div>remove</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have contenteditible = "false" on the inner block in the first place? If you remove that and make that element a `span`, it works just fine.

Comment: i need "test-block" to be immutable

Comment: After a bit of research, I believe this is an issue with Chromium (your example "works" on Chrome and Edge, but Firefox behaves as one would expect). I've submitted a bug report at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1321882

Comment: Hello @СергейАнохин have you got some success in this issue. I have also facing this issue. If it is solved can you help me on that. Any help or suggestion is really appreciated

Comment: Try add overflow: hidden

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to  `.content`:

```
.content {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: this is not working